# Generic abstract classes in Java

Tags: java, abstract-class

I'm trying to make a simple little class where I can make something similar to a macro in C/C++. Basically I want to be able to call the following code when I need to perform a few actions though a list of objects, like so:

```
new IteratableList{
   void action() {
       // do something
   }
}.perform();
```

I haven't programmed in Java in quite a while, and I can't figure out what is wrong with my code when I try to add the abstract action method:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;

public abstract class IteratableList<T> {
    public void perfrom(List<T> ls) {
        Iterator<T> l = ls.iterator();
        while (l.hasNext())
            action(l.next());
    }

    private abstract void action(<T> obj);
}
```

My code doesn't get any errors until I type that last method. I get errors telling me to remove abstract from the method header, and when I change that I get a list of other errors. I feel like I missed a fundamental thing here. Does any one see a glaring error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private abstract void action(<T> obj);
```

should be

```
protected abstract void action(T obj);
```

When you have a generic method you have to define it in the method signature as such:

```
protected abstract <T> void action(T obj);
```

**unless** (and this is the case here) the generic parameter is defined at class level.

You should also remove the `private` modifier and make it `protected` instead. `abstract` indicates the method has to be overridden, but `private` indicates subclasses can't access it. `protected` expands the accessibility of `private` to subclasses.

Comment: Why was I downvoted? A comment to clarify would be a lot more helpful.

Comment: Jeroen - because you can't have a private abstract method. Since (by definition) it would have to be `protected` or `public` or `package` for a subclass to override it. I objected to this line `private abstract <T> void action(T obj);`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: that's right underneath it. I focused on the faulty generic assignment rather than the accessor at first. I'll edit it to prevent misunderstandings.

Comment: Sorry. I must have missed it the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
private abstract void action(<T> obj);
```

I think you want

```
protected abstract void action(T obj);
```

The syntax for the generic was wrong, and you can't have a private abstract method.